# OpenShift Error SQL Exception

Tags: mysql, openshift, sqlexception

OpenShift Error SQL Exception

Hello, I am starting to create an app in OpenShift. The deploy happens normally, without errors. 
While I'm trying to query the database from my application I get this error:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
    at com.nextinfo.gengtask.beans.UsuarioFacade$$$view11.edit(Unknown Source)
    at com.nextinfo.gengtask.managebean.LoginSistemaBean.testeLoginUsuario(LoginSistemaBean.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3006)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2908)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3237)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 74 more
```

I can't understand this:

> java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer
>   ('root'@'localhost') does not exist

Anywhere in my aplication I try to connect as root

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="gengtaskPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My standalone.xml is unchanged

Do I have to create a file as in the link below to my app?
https://github.com/openshift/kitchensink-example/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "anywhere in my application i try to connect as root"? You should use environment variables in order to deal with database user and password with openshift: https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html

Comment: @CSchulz what I mean is that the container is trying to connect as root instead of the configured user